# how to show a raspberry gps activity in my android app

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, raspberry-pi2

I have a raspberry pi2 with a microstack gps module and I want to show the movement of the gps in an android app with a predefined polyline, I've already have the android app done but I have absolutely no idea how to get the activity of the gps to be shown in the app.. could anyone give some ideas on this please? I don't want the code I'm just asking for like ideas :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of communication between the pi, so depending on your need Bluetooth would probably be the best. Then write some basic code for the pi to open a Bluetooth socket through some kind a Bluetooth module (E.g. HC-05 module). Then have the Android device connect to the master device and open another Bluetooth socket on the Android device. Once the communication has been established, you can simply send the GPS data through the sockets in plain text or raw bytes.